# Arithmethic Progression problem!

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Given that the first term of an arithmetic progression is $5$ and the sum of the first eight terms is equal to the sum of the following four terms, find the common difference.

What do they mean by " sum of the first eight terms is equal to the sum of the following four terms " ?

Can you show the equation??

Is it something like $S_8=S_{12}-S_4$ ? I am stuck here

Sorry my english is terrible

Comment: sum of first 8 terms is equal to the sum of (9th +10th+11th+12th) term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^8 a_i = \sum\limits_{i = 9}^{12}a_i$, where $a_i$ is $i$th term given by $a_i = a_1 + (i-1)d$, and $a_1 = 5$.

Answer (score 0):

$a=5$
sum of the first 8 terms: $S_8=\frac{n}{2}(2a+(n-1)d)$ where $n=8$

sum of the following four terms: $T_9+T_{10}+T_{11}+T_{12}$

By sum of the first eight terms is equal to the sum of the following four terms, we have:

$\frac{n}{2}(2a+(n-1)d)=T_9+T_{10}+T_{11}+T_{12}$

$\frac{8}{2}(10+(8-1)d)=a+8d+a+9d+a+10d+a+11d$

$(40+28d)=(20+38d)$

solving for d:

$20=10d$   therefore $d=2$